# BadDeviceToken error when testing chat push notification

Tags: getstream-io

Any idea what we might be getting that error?

We configured APN via CLI:

```
APN: Enabled
APN - Host: https://api.push.apple.com
APN – Auth Type: TOKEN
APN – Key ID: *********
APN – Notification Template {...}
```

But are getting the following error when testing:

```
apn: publishing the message failed with error: BadDeviceToken
```

The error also shows my device id. How can I make sure it's the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: Simply need to make sure your development endpoint for APNs is the correct one. In our case, we had to pick "Development"

Comment: that's indeed correct, I recommend marking this as the correct answer.